# Why is this loop ignoring my instructions?

Tags: java, for-loop

As practice, I was using the Robot class to make the mouse draw a square on the screen.(not actually drawing, but moving the mouse to create a square shape, whenever it get's to the last loop, it always ignores whatever coordinates I give it, and it never exists out of the loop. It just remains in it's own corner. Where did I go wrong?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;


public class RoBotPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        int a = 500;
        int b = 500;

        Robot myRobot = new Robot();
        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            myRobot.delay(25);
            myRobot.mouseMove(i, a);
        }
        for (int i = 500; i<600; i++) {
            myRobot.delay(25);
            myRobot.mouseMove(100, i);
        }
        for (int i = 100; i<200; i--) {
            myRobot.delay(25);
            myRobot.mouseMove(i, 600);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            myRobot.delay(25);
            myRobot.mouseMove(i, a);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 100; i<200;i--)` This will be true a rrrrrrrrrrrrreally long time. Until you get an integer underflow.

Comment: The debugger should be your best friend along with breakpoints.

Comment: the delay() method manages the speed.

Comment: If you have 100 apples and you can only go into the loop if you have less than 200 apples, and every pass in the loop you eat 1 apple. ( in this hypothical scenario you can eat a negative ammount of apples). How meny times will yo go trough the loop? The answer is: 2,147,483,748 times.

Comment: Q: Why is this loop ignoring my instructions? A: It isn't. You may get better help if you have a better question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your third loop, the condition will always be true (or at least until you get an integer underflow), as you start from 100 and then *decrease*, but wait for the number to reach 200.

```
for (int i = 100; i < 200; i--) {
    myRobot.delay(25);
    myRobot.mouseMove(i, 600);
}
```

You probably meant either

```
for (int i = 200; i > 100; i--) {
```

or

```
for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
```

Comment: Well now all the loops do run, so now i'll just have to figure out the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your third loo within your code:

```
for (int i = 100; i < 200; i--) {
    myRobot.delay(25);
    myRobot.mouseMove(i, 600);
}
```

This look is always running because the condition is always true. You will have to modify this in order for it to work properly.